# Loop needs to reference list returned by terminal in notebook

Tags: python, ipython

I have a folder structure with 3 folder X,Y and Z. Each of these folders contains 3 files X1.csv, X2.csv, X3.csv, Y1.csv, Y2.csv, Y3.csv, Z1.csv, Z2.csv, Z3.csv.

In my jupyter notebook I can do the following:

```
folders = ['X','Y','Z']  
for f in folders:
    a = !ls data/X
    print(a)
```

This retruns the following:

```
['X1.csv', 'X2.csv', 'X3.csv']
['X1.csv', 'X2.csv', 'X3.csv']
['X1.csv', 'X2.csv', 'X3.csv']
```

I want to change `!ls data/X` so that it uses `f` instead of the hard-coded `X` but if I change data/X to a string 'data/' and concatenate f to the end of it then I does not return anything.

---

note

I could import os and then use listdir but I'm wondering if the above is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do not use magical notebook commands to do something that [can be easily done with pure python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm). Magic notebook commands are supposed to be used for quick hacks and supporting non-python functionality, not to be actually placed as a part of your code.

However, if for odd reason you really **have to**, you need to reference your variables with bash like-way (`$variable` instaed of `variable`)

```
folders = ['X','Y','Z']  
for f in folders:
    a = !ls data/$f
    print(a)
```